# Does Android only install device size's resources?

Tags: android, resources, google-play, apk

For the same images, I store several copies of different sizes in my Android project (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi). Now if a user installs my application on lets say a mdpi device, does it only copy the mdpi files to the device, and not use too much storage space? (maybe takes something from hdpi if missing)

If so, will the Android market show the size for 'your' device only, or the size of the full apk?

Answer (score 2):

As [blackbelt notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657423/5171), all resources in an APK will be installed on the device.  However, if you really need to restrict this, you can use the Market's [multiple APK functionality](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) to deliver tailored APKs to different devices.  Google recommends that you use a single APK if possible, but the multiple APK route might make sense if your configuration-specific resources are particularly large.

Comment: ok, but why install everything? It can't be too hard to check: `device=mdpi` -> `selectMdpiResources()`, and just look at a different density level if not available in the device's one. Right?